# Max diode current half wave rectifier

Tags: rectifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOeAA7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Given a half wave rectifier composed of a sinusoidal source with peak voltage \$V_p\$ with freequency f, diode, parallel to load capacitor and load resistor \$R_L\$:

I want to calculate maximum diode current in terms of ripple voltage, peak voltage and load current; supposing that load current is constant and given by \$I_L= V_{out}/R_L\$. V_out is the capacitor voltage drop and it is equal to peak voltage. This max current is produced at the moment when the capacitor just starts to charge after the discharge period. I know how to calculate the average current, but can't get the max one. In some books I found that it is more or less the double of the average current. But I want to know the exact way to find it out.

This is an edit:
Due to answer i got till now I will clarifie a bit what I am looking for.
To get the average diode current during capacitor charge I find charge lost:
$$Q=V_{riple}C$$ and and equate it to charge supplied by source to capacitor
$$Q_{lost}=(i_{Dav}-I_L)\Delta t$$
The charging time interval is $$\Delta t =(\sqrt{2V_{ripple}/V_p})/\omega$$
Using this expretions I find that the average current in the diode is:
$$i_{Dav}=I_L(1+\pi\sqrt{2V_p/V_{ripple}})$$
(I_L is considered constant and equal to V_P/R_L)
At the moment when the current is maximum in the diode , it's value is
$$i_{Dmax}=I_L(1+2\pi\sqrt{2V_p/V_{ripple}})$$
I don't know how to arrive at this expretion for maximum current. That's my question.
My try:
$$v=V_p cos(\omega t)$$
$$dv/dt=-V_p\omega sin(\omega t)$$
Now I know that t at which this derivative has to be calculated is \$-\Delta t\$ found before. So I substitute it for t in the derivative and can arrive at something like this: $$i_c=-CV_p\omega\sqrt{2V_{ripple}/V_p}$$ or  $$i_c=-CV_p(2\pi/T)\sqrt{2V_{ripple}/V_p}$$
Is this a right start?

Comment: The diode is *parallel* to the load?  In any case, this is just pointless handwaving without a schematic.

Comment: I = C dv/dt last time I checked.

Comment: I edited the question @OlinLathrop

Comment: You want max current .The volt source is ideal because it has no internal impedence.At turn on there is nothing to limit current because the cap has zero volts on it .Max current at turn on is infinity!?

Comment: Similar to what @Autistic just said, an ideal voltage source, flowing through an ideal diode into an ideal cap that's currently discharged to any level below V(source)-V(diode drop) will cause an infinite current-flow across the diode, in order to instantly charge the cap to V(source)-V(diode drop). - In any real circuit, this is limited to V(difference)/R with R representing all parasitic resistances & inductive reactances of the conductors, diode, and capacitor.

Comment: But the question is, how to arrive to the expretion given for max diode current. I agree that it is theoretical and mostly math. It is not a real world situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a homework (mostly math) question so I won't give you the answer, but recall that (for the capacitor):

\$i(t) = C \frac{dv}{dt}\$

and also you may find this trig identity useful: \$\cos(\sin^{-1}(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}\$

We can also assume that the load current is flowing through the diode while it is conducting. The peak current will occur at the first point where the diode begins to conduct, because that is where the derivative is maximum.

Comment: This is not homework. Could you clarifie this a bit more, plz. Should I take v = V_p cos(wt) or v=V_p e^-t/CR  and use the value of this derivative at t when capacitor starts charging? @SpehroPefhany

Comment: If it is not homework you don't really need to worry about this. In any case this is a very theoretical calculation and probably source impedance will play into it. Don't use the exponential- the discharge is linear and you only need the derivative of the input voltage at Vp-Vripple.

Comment: Sry I insist. But I am really interested on how to do this. I wrote in the question my start for the solution. Is it right way, or am I missing something? @SpehroPefhany

Answer (score 0):

In case of ideal components, the inrush current is unlimited. In reality, the voltage source, the diode and the capacitor will have some internal resistance, which will limit the current. You'll need the values of those resistances if you want to do precise calculations.

Rectifying diodes are designed to deal with inrush currents. They allow high non-repetitive peak current, which is usually about 10 times higher than maximum continuous current for the same diode. This is enough to deal with inrush current in many simple designs.

If you need high reliability, or your smoothing capacitor is unusually big, consider adding a small inductive coil in series with the diode.

Comment: I edited the question @DmitryGrigoryev

Comment: Since the excitation voltage is  a sine wave and not an infinitely sharp edge, peak current will not be infinite.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast That is true. I was not theoretical enough to assume that the sine wave can start at any moment, not only at t=0